# Calling ungeneric methods from generic method in java

Tags: java, generics, downcast

Consider the following:

```
public class Doer {
   public static void doStuff(A a) {
       System.out.println("a");
   }
   public static void doStuff(B b) {
    System.out.println("b");
   }
}
```

Where B extends A

And a generic class like this:

```
public class NewClass<T extends A> {
    public void doSomething(T entity) {
        Doer.doStuff(entity);
    }
}
```

If I call this method as follows it prints "a"

```
new NewClass<B>().doSomething(new B());
```

How do I get it to print "b" ?

Thanks in advance

Edit: A dirty solution is to change

```
Doer.doStuff(entity);
```

to

```
if(entity instanceof B){
    Doer.doStuff((B) entity);
}else {
    Doer.doStuff(entity);
}
```

But I'm looking for a solution that does not use instanceof and so that I don't have to add an extra if (C intance of A) ... to NewClass when I make a new Class extending A

Comment: Which object you are passing as Entity. A object or B object [parent/child].

Comment: In java the method to be called is resolved at compile time not run time. This means that you are passing in some subclass of `A` - that is all the compiler knows. `doStuff(A a)` will always be called.

Comment: I think you will have to check the type in the `doStuff`-method which takes an `A`.

Comment: @Boris is there a way to solve this without having to do "if (entity instanceof B) Doer.doStuff((B) entity; else Doer.doStuff(entity); ?

Comment: Given the situation, I think I would move the A/B differences out of Doer and into overriden methods in A and B, and have Doer only have the one DoStuff(A a) call, so that Doer doesn't know the specifics, just A's API. May not be what you need, but not knowing the details, that's what I'd do.

Answer (score 2):

See these questions for answers: [Java Generic / Type Dispatch Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784333/java-generic-type-dispatch-question), [How does Java method dispatch work with Generics and abstract classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452635/how-does-java-method-dispatch-work-with-generics-and-abstract-classes)

Basically, you have these options:

- define `doStuff` as an abstract method on `A`
- try the Visitor pattern
- if possible, use a language (e.g. Xtend) that supports [dynamic dispatch](http://www.eclipse.org/xtend/documentation.html#polymorphicDispatch)

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't do dynamic binding based on the argument type.  The actual method that is invoked is determined at compile time.  So in case of a generic type, the method with `Object` as the parameter type will be invoked.

You could work around this by checking the type with instanceof, but the puristic way of handling this is to leverage polymorphism and using [Double Dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch).  But that is not always an option, since it tightly couples your calling class and your argument class together.

Answer (score 0):

NewClass would have to have two methods also, or you could do something like this:

```
public class NewClass<T extends A> {
    public void doSomething(T entity) {
        if(entity instanceof B){
            Doer.doStuff((B)entity);
        }else if(entity instanceof A){
            Doer.doStuff((A)entity);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Plus, I wouldn't think that would help.

Comment: Sorry, I realized that too, and changed my answer.

Comment: This would indeed work, but I'm looking for a solution that doesn't use instanceof, so that I don't end up with 15 if instanceof else clauses when I have 15 classes extending A that each have their own method in Doer

Comment: Sorry, I don't see a way of doing it without the 15 instanceof checks. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think that in that case you're forced to actually determine entity's type and cast it, as your function doSomething just infers that entity inherits from A.
Basically you could do:

```
public void doSomething(T entity) {
    if (entity instanceof B) {
        Doer.doStuff((B) entity);
    }
    else {
        Doer.doStuff(entity);
    }
}
```